# Do the Q know about and take heed of the Prophets?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-q

I just looked online to see if I could find a theory that I just had.

I was just watching TNG for the umpteenth time (thanks to Netflix), after watching DS9 through to the end first (as my personal favourite series).

Watching TNG Encounter at Farpoint, after they split the disc section away so that the warp section could turn around and face Q, Miles O'Brien is on the battle bridge, but isn't taken by Q. Although everyone else on the battle bridge is taken to the 21st century court, at no stage does Miles get taken or mentioned. It's almost like Q is actively avoiding Miles and leaving him out of his meddling with the humans.

The theory being - is it possible Q was aware of the Prophets and was told to stay away from Miles because of his involvement with the events that would unravel in the battle to come involving Sisko, the Prophets and the Pah-wraith?

It seems that although he boarded DS9 because of Vash, maybe he had heard of "The Sisko" and thought he would meddle whilst he was on board, we know how brash he is, and seeing how quickly he ultimately withdrew never to be seen again after fisticuffs with Sisko, seems odd knowing that he was happy to screw with the TNG crew for several years.

Anyway, I look forward to your thoughts and if there is anything I'm not aware of that can debunk this theory.